# import time data separately from date and without added dates

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, time-series, import-from-csv

When importing a typical intraday 1-minute interval stock data file:

```
data7 = pd.read_csv('Documents/spy1min.txt', parse_dates=[0], index_col=[0, 1], usecols=['Date','Time','Open','High','Low','Close'])
```

The result dataframe looks like this:

```
                  Open    High     Low   Close
Date       Time                                 
2016-12-14 08:01  227.80  227.91  227.76  227.77
           08:02  227.78  227.78  227.77  227.77
           08:03  227.77  227.77  227.77  227.77
           08:04  227.76  227.76  227.76  227.76
```

However, 'Time' part of the index is now a string instead of being recognized as time.

If I set parse_dates=[1] in the above code instead, I get

```
                            Open    High     Low   Close
Date       Time                                               
12/14/2016 2018-12-14 08:01:00  227.80  227.91  227.76  227.77
           2018-12-14 08:02:00  227.78  227.78  227.77  227.77
           2018-12-14 08:03:00  227.77  227.77  227.77  227.77
```

Neither option is ideal: I don't want today's date arbitrarily added to 'Time', but I want 'Time' be represented as real time instead of strings. Is there a way to do that concisely in python?  Thanks a lot!

(p.s. I know that I can combine 'Date' and 'Time' into a single DateTimeindex.  But in my later processing, there are many advantages of keeping 'Date' and 'Time' separate and hierarchical: for example, I often need to run the same time interval analyses in all the different dates.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you can create time column and append to index by `set_index` or convert `time`s to `timedeltas` by [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_timedelta.html):

```
import pandas as pd

temp=u"""Date,Time,Open,High,Low,Close
2016-12-14,08:01,227.80,227.91,227.76,227.77
2016-12-14,08:02,227.78,227.78,227.77,227.77
2016-12-14,08:03,227.77,227.77,227.77,227.77
2016-12-14,08:04,227.76,227.76,227.76,227.76"""
#after testing replace 'pd.compat.StringIO(temp)' to 'filename.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(temp), 
                 index_col=[0], 
                 parse_dates=[0],
                 usecols=['Date','Time','Open','High','Low','Close'])

print (df)
             Time    Open    High     Low   Close
Date                                             
2016-12-14  08:01  227.80  227.91  227.76  227.77
2016-12-14  08:02  227.78  227.78  227.77  227.77
2016-12-14  08:03  227.77  227.77  227.77  227.77
2016-12-14  08:04  227.76  227.76  227.76  227.76
```

---

```
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time']).dt.time
df = df.set_index('Time', append=True)
print (df)
                       Open    High     Low   Close
Date       Time                                    
2016-12-14 08:01:00  227.80  227.91  227.76  227.77
           08:02:00  227.78  227.78  227.77  227.77
           08:03:00  227.77  227.77  227.77  227.77
           08:04:00  227.76  227.76  227.76  227.76

print (df.index.get_level_values(1))
Index([08:01:00, 08:02:00, 08:03:00, 08:04:00], dtype='object', name='Time')

print (type(df.index.get_level_values(1)[0]))
<class 'datetime.time'>
```

---

```
df['Time'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['Time'] + ':00')
df = df.set_index('Time', append=True)
print (df)
                       Open    High     Low   Close
Date       Time                                    
2016-12-14 08:01:00  227.80  227.91  227.76  227.77
           08:02:00  227.78  227.78  227.77  227.77
           08:03:00  227.77  227.77  227.77  227.77
           08:04:00  227.76  227.76  227.76  227.76

print (df.index.get_level_values(1))
TimedeltaIndex(['08:01:00', '08:02:00', '08:03:00', '08:04:00'],
               dtype='timedelta64[ns]', name='Time', freq=None)
```